# Getting variables from res.send in Jade Template

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, pug

I am pretty new to using node.js and Jade. I self taught from some tutorials on udemy and I am having some issues with combining Jade, Express and Backbone per one of the examples. I used res.send to send my user list and my todolist to the jade template but it wont grab the data.

I had to combine my api.js file, index.js and index.jade file to one link due to not having enough rep to post more than 2 links, so I separated them by ----

https://dpaste.de/tZFc

When I load the page, my app is getting all the information:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kw5w1fahjev9by6/appresults.JPG?dl=0

How can I get this in the jade template to render the data, I am really struggling with this and everything I find in tutorials doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

use res.render instead,

```
res.render('path/to/your/jade', {docs: docs, users:users});
```

Get the value in your jade file using `'#{docs}' and '#{users}'`

Comment: The above is correct. If you are sending data to be consumed while also rendering the view, res.render is the method you should be using. Make sure your view is properly annotated in the argument. If your jade file is in the "views" directory of your project simply add, for example,  **res.render("index", {})**, as your app **likely** knows to already look in the views directory. This may not be your case though!